# annotation/xml markups visualizer (for NLP)

Tags: xml, nlp, visualization, stanford-nlp

Is there a tool or package to visualize annotations (for example annotations defined by Stanford CoreNLP)? The annotation can be anything, and I can mark them in text by defining XML markups around them, i.e. by

```
 ... legend superstar, <ProperName>Elton John</ProperName> had  
 a live performance in <Location>Guatemala</Location> in <Date>2012</Date>.
```

So, even something that can take the text and the added XML markups and show it
as highlighted text (i.e. yellow highlighted Elton John, red highlighted Guatemala, and green highlighted 2012, while the rest of the words are not coloured) is good enough as long as it can automatically define separate colours for each markup types (i.e. LocationName, Date, ProperName, etc).

**Note**: I am aware of [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/), but it's a heavy to load and run program and I really don't need its modules, etc as I have developed all I need. I am looking for something that only provides some sort of visualization.

Comment: Check out our server: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html  ...if you run it you can see the brat representation of the annotations in a web browser

Comment: Also check out brat: http://brat.nlplab.org/